# CKEditor Error: The environment is incompatible

Tags: ckeditor

I am facing a issue related to ckeditor.
When I tried to load the ckeditor on my page it give me environment in incompatible error in console of the browsers.
Please help.

Comment: Got the solutions.. Just by adding config.jqueryOverrideVal = true; in config.js of ckeditor it works... :-)

Comment: According to the docs this setting is experimental. If you want to keep the existing limitation, you might put a try catch block around the ckeditor initialization code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when running ckeditor in an officially non-supported environment, such as an iPad or tablet or old browser. An exception can also be thrown by jquery adapter for ckeditor.

Per the [documentation on unsupported environments](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_unsupported_environments), you can force compatibility with:

```js
        CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
```